# TabBar in TableViewController is not at the bottom

Tags: uitableview, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to add a tabBar to my TableViewController but it is not a the bottom it just act like a cell

Here is a screenShot:

[image: ScreenShot of]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `UITableviewController` storyboard scene, every `Tab Bar` or `Toolbar` you drag in it is automatically put into the tableView [tableFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView).

If you don't want that, you have to create an `UIViewController` scene. You will therefore be able to drag your `Tab Bar` or `Toolbar` in it, set its auto layout constraints and then add your `UITableView` in the `UIViewController` scene (see image below).

[image]

**However**, there is another solution. Select your `Navigation Controller` scene and go to the Attributes Inspector. In the Simulated Metrics, go to Bottom Bar and select "Translucent Tab Bar" or "Translucent toolbar". Then, select your `UITableviewController` scene and repeat the previous operation (see the picture below).

[image]

If you do so, all controllers following your `Navigation Controller` will have a `Tab Bar` or `Toolbar` (that's another problem that can also be fixed).

Comment: But if i do like the first solution i can't use function for my tableView. I have changed: class className: UITableViewController
To class className: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate. I have tried to println something in a tableView function but it seems like it doesn't get called

Comment: An i've remove "override" before calling tableView function cause it was telling me a error

Comment: Yes, remove the various `override` before your tableView methods declaration. Don't forget to create a "tableView" IBOutlet in your viewController subclass and dont forget to link your tableView datasource and delegate to your viewController. Using a tableView inside a viewController is quite common. You will find a lot of examples about it with Google and SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use autoLayout to pin it to the bottom

Comment: When i select my tabBar and click on pin i can't click anything in it it's all gray

Comment: @ClémentBisaillon select the tabBar in the Document Outline.

Comment: I do. I thinks it's because it is in a tableViewController